# replace cross sell with related on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, related-products

I know the correct answer is "why should you, cross sell products are supposed to be shown there".
But i got a stubborn customer who wants to show the related products on the cart page.

What is the correct way to do this?
Simply changing the type on `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.html` isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might forgot to override the argument.
It can be done like this.

```
<update name="checkout.cart.crosssell">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
    </arguments>
</update>
```

Replace `crosssell` with the type you want (for example `related`).

Comment: Yup, allready tried that. But seems like i didn't do it right then. Thanks!